# jQuery request returns 502 bad gateway error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a strange error occurring for me and I don't know why. I've just loaded my locally developed project onto my server for testing. Everything seems to be working perfectly locally but when I use a particular feature which when a dropdown for changes an ajax call grabs the requested data.

This works perfectly locally but I am now getting this 502 error. The links are correct and I just don't know where to go from here.

Any ideas why this could possibly happen?

Here's my controller

```
public function getQualifications()
{
    $quals = Qualification::where('sector', '=', $_GET['quals'])->get();
    $options = array();
    foreach($quals as $qual) {
        $options[$qual->id] =  array(
            $qual->sector,
            $qual->title,
            $qual->cost
        );
    }
    return $options;
}
```

And my jquery...

```
$('select#sector').on('change', function(){
    $('.sector_qual').remove();

    var value = $(this).val();
    var holder = $('#holder');
    var holderClass = holder.attr('class');

    if( holderClass === 'hide' ) {
        holder.removeClass('hide');
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://" + window.location.host + "/ajax/qualifications",
        data: {quals: value},
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<tr class="sector_qual"><td>' + val[1] + '</td><td>' + val[2] + '</td><td><input name="qualification" id="' + key + '" type="radio" value="' + key + '" class="" /><input name="max_value" id="max_value' + key + '" type="hidden" value="' + val[2] + '" /></td></tr>');
        });

        var myQuals = items.join('');

        $('#qual-holder thead').after(myQuals);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes. you didnt include your code. Thats why!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that the answer was due to a conflict with a debugbar I was using, removing that did the trick.